Distributions Supported on Subset of Positive Definite Matrices
Fix positive integer $d$. Given a subset of indices $I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, d\}$, write $S_I$ for the set of all $d \times d$ positive definite matrices such that the $i$th diagonal entry $S_{i,i}$ equals to $1$ for all $i \in I$.
Question : is there any concrete examples of matrix variate distributions supported on $S_I$? If $I$ is the empty set, then $S_I$ is just all $d \times d$ positive definite matrices and the inverse Wishart distribution will be a good example.
Motivation : I am doing Bayesian statistics on covariance matrix. To be precise, given data $X_1,\ldots, X_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the statistical model I pose is that they are all independent identically distributed $N_d(\mu, \Sigma)$, with unknown mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and partially unknown $d \times d$ positive definite $\Sigma$, where the known part about $\Sigma$ is that I $\textit{know}$ some components have unit variance. The problem above translates to finding a good proper prior distribution.
